# How do I memoize the last result in a chain of observables?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I've modelled a navigation concept reactively, (a user navigating forward and backward pages) but I'm having trouble optimizing it using Reactive Extensions. I'm sure it's some kind of buffering or sharing operator, but I'm not quite sure which one it is or where to shove it.

This is a working, simplified example of what I've implemented, in TypeScript and with rxjs.

Each time the user clicks, we increment it by one step. (In reality, there is a network request in here which might return a new step or none, hence why this is not a simple `+ 1`.)

```js
describe('navigate', () => {
  it('should increment', () => {
    const initial = Observable.of(0);
    const plusOne = (ns: Observable<number>) => ns.pipe(map(n => n + 1), tap(x => console.log("Computed", x)));
    const clicks = Observable.from([plusOne, plusOne, plusOne]);
    const expected = cold("(wxyz|)", { w: 0, x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 });

    const result = clicks.pipe(
      scan(
        (s: Observable<number>, x: (ns: Observable<number>) => Observable<number>) => x(s),
        initial),
      startWith(initial),
      switchAll(),
    )

    expect(result).toBeObservable(expected);
  })
})
```

It produces the correct output, and the test passes.

But in terms of execution, in the console you'll see this printed:

```
Computed 1
Computed 1
Computed 2
Computed 1
Computed 2
Computed 3
```

which makes sense, but if the `plusOne` operation is expensive (e.g. a network request) it won't do to have the `plusOne`s computed from the start every time.

How do I memoize the result of the last `plusOne` so that subsequent `plusOne`s need not calculate the entire chain again?
Or if I'm looking at this the wrong way, how should I be approaching this problem?

### Attempt

Since the top of this question, I did think of one solution.

```js
const result = clicks.pipe(
      scan(
        (s: Observable<number>, x: (ns: Observable<number>) => Observable<number>) => x(s).pipe(shareReplay(1)),
        initial),
      startWith(initial),
      switchAll(),
    )
```

which executes like:

```
Computed 1
Computed 2
Computed 3
```

However I *think* this leads to a chain which would look like:

```
xs.map(x => x + 1).shareReplay(1).map(x => x + 1).shareReplay(1).map(x => x + 1).shareReplay(1)
```

and which I don't think would be terribly efficient (if each `shareReplay(1)` caches a value). Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You only need one shareReplay(1) at the end no? or use a behavior subject to just return the last valid result.

Comment: Why are you passing Observables instead of values? Wouldnt it be easier if you operated on number instead of Observable<number>?

Comment: I think i would handle the api calls inside of a concatMap. What is executed inside of a concatMap is guaranteed to execute sequentially. Inside of that concatMap you could use withLatestFrom to return the result of the last executed api call, and in ther last step inside that concatMap i would update the last executed result (in either a state store, or simply a subject). So you would just get the last response, get a new response, update last response in a sequential way.

Comment: @FanCheung, if you're referring to the chain, that is just a representation of the observable that would be composed at runtime using my attempt. If you're suggesting placing a shareReplay(1) at the end then no, that would be shareReplay'ing for subscribers of 'result'.

Comment: @Davy RE: "Why are you passing Observables instead of values?". It's because: 
"In reality, there is a network request in here which might return a new step or none, hence why this is not a simple + 1."

Comment: @Davy Yes, storing the last result in a variable might work if 'result' only had one subscriber or if I share()'d it. I'd prefer to express it in rxjs and not have to manage my own side-effects.

Comment: I wouldnt store it in a variable, but a state store. You are not side-effecting when you are manipulating the source stream.